# Merging in ModelBuilder after Running Script?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, merge

I have multiple inputs running through various processes throughout my model. At the end of these processes they are all merged together and output into one final feature class. This was working fine until I decided to put a script tool at an earlier point in the model on one of my functions, essentially stopping the process if a certain value was false. The script tool works well, but now my final merged output is not performing correctly. I took the model apart in pieces and ran through to isolate the problem, and it would appear that when the script tool stops the process, even though the merge function has multiple correct inputs, it will not merge anything together.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue or a workaround?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.

Comment: I don't get it! Would it be possible to get a screenshot of the Model?

Comment: Need more details like screenshot of your Python script tool's parameters (as well as screenshot of the Model as requested by @Nathanus)

Comment: Yes, I have figured out how to create a sub-model within a master model that eliminates the need for the script and cleans up the general work flow of the model. I now have a different issue, which I have just posted complete with pictures at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14030/problems-integrating-sub-model-into-master-model

Answer (score 2):

If your Merge function is waiting to grab the output from the process that stops 'if a certain value was false', then it may be failing when it doesn't get that value.

Try using the Collect Values ModelBuilder tool, then feeding the data from that tool into the Merge.