# Problems Integrating Sub-Model into Master Model

Tags: arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, modelbuilder

I am attempting to integrate a iterative model into a master model to merge all of the outputs of the iterative model into one feature class. However, when I attempt to set the output of the sub-model (iterative) as the input for the merge tool, it will not allow it. I have attached two pictures of each model. Any suggestions?

I am using ArcMap 10.

Thanks,

Eric [image: Iterative Model]

[image: Composite Model]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have successfully manipulated the sub-model and the outer model to achieve my desired outcome. I ended up getting rid of the Collect Values tool and using the Append tool. I am attaching two images of the models for anyone in the future that might have the same issues. The top image is the iterated sub-model and below it is the composite outer model.

Eric

[image: Iterated Model]

[image: Composite Model]

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Collect Values but was looking for something like it at 9.3 (am assuming it was new at 10) to use with Append, so I believe I understand your requirement.

I would expect that Collect Values would NOT be part of your iterated sub-model but would be an input to your Merge tool instead so that it can collect the values output by the multiple runs of your sub-model.